# Partition of an Array List such that i can have fixed object in it?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am looking to convert a List of N objects into chunks of arraylist, it should be done in such a way that it should not have duplicate and chunks should be of certain size.

Example- ArrayList size - 100
Chunk size 20
Arraylist should have 5 chunks in it.

Comment: Please add more details to the question like what you have tried so far. Refer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to fix this problem, and i resolved it by using a workflow as i wanted to perform partition of list in a way where i can have more control on it and following camunda workflow was useful.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Iterate over the list and every "size" element create a new chunk:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> split(Collection<T> data, int size)
{
    List<List<T>> lists=new ArrayList<>((data.size()+size-1)/size);
    List<T> list=new ArrayList<>(size);
    for(T t:data)
    {
        list.add(t);
        if(list.size()==size)
        {
            lists.add(list);
            list=new ArrayList<>(size);
        }
    }
    if(list.size()>0) lists.add(list);
    return lists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/30.1.1-jre)'s [Lists.partition(List list, int size)](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-):

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
List<List<Integer>> sublists = Lists.partition(integers, 3);
System.out.println(sublists);
```

Output:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7]
]
```

Comment: If by "not have duplicate" you mean that the original array might have duplicates - you can remove duplicates beforehand, like this: `noDuplicatesList= integers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());` then call `Lists.partition(noDuplicatesList, 3)`